# Kendo headerTemplate textbox editable mode

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Kendo UI added combobox. When combobox flyout In header I need to add couple of textboxes. Which can be achieved using headerTemplate. But its not editable.

Here i  added peace of and and sample design for your concern. Can anyone suggest me how to overcome this issue.

> Here is my peace of code and sample design:

```
headerTemplate : '<div class="topdiv">'+
"<input type='text' class='height-30'><input type='text' class='height-30'><input type='text' class='height-30'>"+
"</div>",
```

**Sample Design Screenshot**

[image: Please open sample design]